# The process cannot access the file '...' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#

I searched alot about this Exception's solutions but without any result yet.
This is my code,
The exception is being thrown at the line:

```
 BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(FI.Open(FileMode.Open));
```

Note that the exception doesn't raise every time.. I know that this is strange.
Any one have an idea?

```
    FileInfo FI = new FileInfo("e:\\cc.accdb");
    if (FI.Exists)
        FI.Delete();

    GC.Collect();

    FI.Create();

    byte[] bb = { 54, 87, 98, 57, 65 };
    BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(FI.Open(FileMode.Open));
    BW.Write(bb);
```

Comment: `FileInfo.Create` returns a `FileStream` object. You are ignoring that. Presumably that object is locking you out. Why don't you pass `FI.Create()` straight to your `BinaryWriter`? What's the point of GC.Collect(). That seems pointless.

Answer (score 4):

My guess is because you're not closing the handle to the file.  You need to release the handle when you are done with it, otherwise it'll persist.  Wrap the Writer object in a `using` block to dispose of it when complete to handle this.

And if it's not your application with a handle on the file, run procmon to see what process has a lock on that particular file.

[Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) is a link to download Process Monitor in case you don't have it.  It's an invaluable tool, and if you haven't needed it...you will.

Comment: you should prolly wrap the writer in a `using` block and flush it out before closing just to be sure.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs agreed, good point on utilization.  I have edited my answer to reflect.

Comment: Another useful program is named Unlocker. It's very handy for dealing with locked files.

Comment: @PatrickPitre just downloaded it, that looks pretty cool.  Thanks!

Comment: It integrates into Explorer as well, so you can right-click any file, and run Unlocker from there. Glad you like it!

Answer (score 3):

If you change the code to something like this it will work:

```
string path = "e:\\cc.accdb";

byte[] bb = { 54, 87, 98, 57, 65 };
BinaryWriter BW = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Create));
BW.Write(bb);
```